# sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column expression, FROM clause, or columns clause element expected, got sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 2 flask models. Simplified below:

```
class Product(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  weight = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)

class Package(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  quantity = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
  product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'))
  product = db.relationship('Product')

  @hybrid_property
  def total_weight(self):
     return self.quantity * (self.product.weight if self.product else 0)

  @total_weight.expression
  def total_weight(cls):
     weight_column = select([Product.weight]).where(Product.id == cls.product_id).label('product_weight')
     
     return case([(cls.product_id.isnot(None), cast(cls.quantity * weight_column, Integer)),], else_=0).label('total_weight')
```

I'm trying find the sum of total_weight of all packages, using the following query:

```
db.session.query(func.sum(Package.total_weight)).scalar()
```

I also tried:

```
db.session.query(func.sum(Package.total_weight.expression())).scalar()
```

But in both cases, I get the following error:
`sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column expression, FROM clause, or other columns clause element expected, got [<sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x1103e0220>]. Did you mean to say select(<sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x1103e0220>)?`

I'm looking for either the correct sql express or an alternative to hybrid_property expression.

If it helps, my current database is a sqlite3 database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using legacy syntax despite having SQLAlchemy 2.0 installed.

Change

```
select([Product.weight])
```

to

```
select(Product.weight)
```

and

```
case([(cls.product_id.isnot(None), cast(cls.quantity * weight_column, Integer)),], else_=0).label('total_weight')
```

to

```
case((cls.product_id.isnot(None), cast(cls.quantity * weight_column, Integer)), else_=0).label('total_weight')
```

In both cases you are removing square brackets which are no longer used in SQLA 2.0.  See [this entry](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_20.html#select-no-longer-accepts-varied-constructor-arguments-columns-are-passed-positionally) in the [migration guide](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_20.html).